# IE Doesn't Display 3 Floated Sections Correctly

Tags: css, html

On Firefox/Chrome/Opera/Etc, this CSS works great and the 3 columns are side by side. On IE, the columns are vertical and are not side by side.

What's an easy fix/hack for this? Thanks!

```
<style>
.col1 {
    float: left;
    width: 270px;
    position: relative;
    padding: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.col2 {
    float: left;
    width: 270px;
    position: relative;
    padding: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.col3 {
    float: left;
    width: 270px;
    position: relative;
    padding: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
</style>
```

The html:

```
   <body>
    <section class="col1">
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of 
        the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
    </section>

    <section class="col2">
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of 
        the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
    </section>

    <section class="col3">
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of 
        the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
    </section>
    </body>
```

Comment: What version of IE are you referring to?

Comment: html5 tag doesnt work for IE8 and below. try section{display:block;}

Comment: @Shadow_boi display:block; is not enough. Then the section or other elements still won't have any functionallity. My anwser solves this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this script in your head section:

```
<!--[if IE]>
<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

IE 8< doesn't recognize the `section` element. The problem is that browsers have special treatment for tags they don't recognize at all; basic things like styles being applied and being able to contain sub-items won't work.